# Limit of $ \frac {f(x)-f(y)} {x-y}$ when $ x\to y$

Tags: limits, analysis, derivatives

Can the limit with two variables

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow y}\frac {f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} $$

be evaluated in the "large"? When $x\to y, ~ $ we have the $\dfrac {0}{0}$ form that cannot be evaluated.

When the variables are separated only by an infinitesimal difference $h,k$ clearly

$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(x)-f(x-h)}{x-(x-h)}= f'(x); \lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(y)-f(y-k)}{y-(y-k)}=f'(y);  $$

It could be  some function of $x,f'(x)$ and $y,f'(y)$, or so I imagined but am clueless. Could not find it amenable to proceed with series expansions. Thanking you in advance.

As suggested by PierreCarre in this context can we find out the limit

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to (\alpha,\alpha)}\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} $$ of $ ~\dfrac{0}{0}$ form when independent variables go to the same $\alpha $ ?

Comment: The limit you are asked to evaluate is independent of $x$, it is a function of $y$. It makes no sense to say its value is $f'(x)$. And if you are doing limits seriously then forget this "infinitesimal difference" stuff.

Comment: Yes.. here it is applicable for finite differences that do vanish while evaluating the limit. Please note that we have the $0/0$ form that can be at all considered for further limit evaluation, imho.

Comment: I habve no idea what you mean by "in the large". You should probably rephrase your question so we understand what are you really asking... As it is, the value of that limit is obviously and without any margin for creativity $f'(y)$.

Comment: Could not explain well enough perhaps. With the conventional one variable the derivative quotient is seen with locally linear increments . My question relates essentially to a non-linearity relation with two variables.

Comment: Maybe you want to address something like
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (\alpha,\alpha)}\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} ? $$

Comment: Yes, thanks; much better stated this way with a common constant tendency  for independent variables.

Answer (score 0):

By simple substitution $x = y + h$, we have
$$ \lim_{x\to y} \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(y+h)-f(y)}{h} = f'(y)$$ by [definition of derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Definition).

Actually, it's a common alternative to write derivative at point $c$ as $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$, instead of $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}.$

---

If we look at $\lim_{(x,y)\to (c,c)}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ instead, we can immediately see that if that limit exists, it's equal to $f'(c)$ by looking at limits either along the line $y = c$, or $x = c$. So, $f$ being differentiable at $c$ is a necessary condition. But, is it sufficient?

No. We can do two things, either restrict domain of $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$, or assume stronger conditions on $f$.

**1. Restricting domain**

What I can tell you is that the limit exists when restricted to any line passing through $(c,c)$ (except, of course, $y=x$). To see this write
$$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} = \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\cdot\frac{x-c}{x-y}+\frac{f(y)-f(c)}{y-c}\cdot\frac{y-c}{y-x}\tag{1}$$

and note that $\frac{x-c}{x-y} = \frac{1}{1-k}$ and $\frac{y-c}{y-x} = \frac{-k}{1-k}$ are constant on each line of the form $y - c = k(x-c),\, k \neq 1,$ and they sum to $1$, so from $(1)$ it's clear that the limit will be $f'(c)$ along each of those lines.

Unfortunately, functions $\frac{x-c}{x-y}$ and $\frac{y-c}{y-x}$ don't have a limit at $(c,c)$, so it's not clear from $(1)$ that the limit we want exists. However, we can furthermore write
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-f'(c)\right| &= \left|\left(\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)\right)\frac{x-c}{x-y}+\left(\frac{f(y)-f(c)}{y-c}-f'(c)\right)\frac{y-c}{y-x}\right|\\
&\leq \left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)\right|\left|\frac{x-c}{x-y}\right|+\left|\frac{f(y)-f(c)}{y-c}-f'(c)\right|\left|\frac{y-c}{y-x}\right|\\
&< \frac\varepsilon{2R}\left(\left|\frac{x-c}{x-y}\right|+\left|\frac{y-c}{y-x}\right|\right)
\end{align}
when $0<\max\{|x-c|,|y-c|\}<\delta_R$ for a suitable $\delta_R$. If we restrict domain of $\frac{f(x)-f(x)}{x-y}$ to $\mathcal D_R = \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid \frac 12 - R \leq \frac{x-c}{x-y}\leq \frac 12 + R\}$ for $R\geq \frac 12$, we can see that $\left|\frac{x-c}{x-y}\right|+\left|\frac{y-c}{y-x}\right| \leq 2R$ on $\mathcal D_R$, so by the above we have $\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-f'(c)\right| < \varepsilon$ when $\|(x-c,y-c)\|_\infty< \delta_R$ and $(x,y)\in\mathcal D_R$.

Here's how $\mathcal D_R$ looks like for $R= \frac 12$ and $R = 5$, with the red dot having coordinates $(c,c)$:

[image]

To see that simple existence of derivative $f'(c)$ is not enough for the general limit, consider

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} x^2\sin(\frac 1x),&\,x\neq 0\\ 0,&\,x=0 \end{cases}$$ which is differentiable at $0$ with $f'(0) = 0$, but not continuously differentiable at $0$.

To find a curve which doesn't lie in any of $\mathcal D_R$, we consider a curve to which $y = x$ is tangent, such as $y = \sin x$. Then the limit along the curve $y = \sin x$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(\sin x)}{x-\sin x}$$ doesn't exist.

Another example is $f(x) = x|x|$ which is continuously differentiable at $0$, but not twice differentiable. Looking at the limit along the same curve $y = \sin x$ this times gives us $f'(0)$. This might be coincidence or it might suggest that $f$ being continuously differentiable at $c$ is sufficient for the general limit to exist.

**2. Stronger conditions on $f$.**

Let $f$ be differentiable on some interval $I$ containing $c$ and $f'$ continuous at $c$. Let $(x_n,y_n)$ be a sequence in $I^2\setminus\{(x,x)\mid x\in I\}$ that converges to $(c,c)$. Then, by Lagrange's mean value theorem there exists sequence $c_n$ converging to $c$ such that $\frac{f(x_n)-f(y_n)}{x_n-y_n} = f'(c_n)$ which converges to $f'(c)$ by continuity of $f'$ at $c$.

This proves $\lim_{(x,y)\to (c,c)} \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} = f'(c)$.

Comment: Imagine downvoting obviously correct answer without any explanation.

Comment: I was also puzzled by the downvote, but that's democracy! Anyway, +1!

Comment: Merci. Pursuing a deviant path is almost always risky!

Comment: @Narasimham perhaps my edit will be of help.

Comment: Yes thanks, but let me check some special cases before getting a feel of the general case.

Comment: @Narasimham, seems like $f$ should be continuously differentiable at least for the general limit to exist. You can try $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$ along the curve $y = \sin x$. If I'm not mistaken, the limit $x\to 0$ shouldn't exist. If you look at $f(x) = x|x|$ which is continuously differentiable at $0$, but not twice differentiable, the limit exists along the same curve $y = \sin x$ and is $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: @Narasimham, another edit. Seems like $f$ being continuously differentiable at $c$ is enough for the limit to exist.